# How to master a game where the player group is not a group IG

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic

So, I've had this crazy idea of making a new type of pen and paper RPG, the goal is to enforce two principles :

- The players are important in their own, not as a group
- There is no prerequisite for the player to create a group, and the GM does not create an initial situation where the Characters create a group.

So basically, the result would be a dynamic meta-story involving multiple main-characters and sub stories.

My first idea was to involve 3 GMs and 3 PCs, separated in 3 groups in a different table (but in the same room) :

- In the 3 GMs, there is a SMG (super GM) which hold supreme authority over the universe and the setting.
- Each GM has an environment, and a story to follow more or less, but he has to arrive at a specific point in space and time.
- During their stories, the PCs will modify their environment, impacting the ones of the other PCs (the GMs can document that so the other GM can take this into account)
- The players can, and surely will, meet, and interact. They will share the same table for a time, and could split at any point.
- When everybody arrives at the space time point, they share some kind of plot-ending, leading to the conclusion of the story. During that part, the two non SGM GMs become PC/NPCs, preferably bringing new variables to the environment, and not knowing the ideas of the SGM)
- The conclusion of the story has a default state, but is expected to be completely changed through the choices of the players, and the outcome of their final encounter.

Note that this is my idea of the concept below, to give you a better understanding of what I have in mind, which does NOT mean I want to stick to that plan because I have some big problems :

- The mastering needs to be very strict/efficient to end up in a state that enable the conclusion, which might be unfun for the players ?
- The players need to have some idea of what's going on, but the best would be that they do not know who is who while playing until they meet. (I though about a map in the center that shows the different events in some ways that only the GMs fully understand, to give some visual feedback to the players)
- The time management to get the events synchronized is pretty much impossible ?
- The dynamism need to keep the players/GMs entertained all long, but the encounters have to be restricted so that nothing too bad happens (a player dying at that point might be really frustrating).

So my question is, is this actually viable ? If not, is there a way to solve that ?

As a footnote : I already GMed Multi tables (4-5 tables of 4-5 players in a room, moving through a 8-10 hours plot interacting with each others), but it is still group-based RPG, so a single player has less chance to be bored (he can talk with other players), or to be frustrated about dying (the individual are less important), which is why I had the idea above. This setting works great, but I'm afraid it wont work for what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you've missed a whole lot of RPGs out there. There are lots of titles that break the D&D/Vampire/Werewolf trope of playing people in a group, from Trollbabe or Don't Rest Your Head (where the players take turns and the characters might never meet) to Apocalypse World or Dogs in the Vineyard, where the game works if there's intra-"party" conflict. Maybe we could meet in the [chat] to shed some light on the state of the art before asking questions with premises like this one, shall we?

Comment: Yeah, there's systems that more or less allow this kind of play already

Comment: Yep, the nice thing is that if you take the time to check out the many games that do non-party play, you can learn a lot of what works and doesn't work and avoid falling into pitfalls people have already discovered.  Primetime Adventures, 1001 Nights, Dirty Secrets, Drifter's Escape, Hot Guys Making Out... you've got a lot of options to look through out there.

Comment: While the letter might be asking for an off-topic comment, the actual obvious intent is quite on-topic: **"is there a game who satisfies this scenario? how does it do that?"**.

Comment: @Lohoris That would still be too broad: there are many systems, and they each use different methods out of the many ways to accomplish it. Picking just one would be incomplete, but enumerating every method would be way too long for our format.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie there are so many games _with 1:1 GMs:Players_? Or you mean there are many games that get to the same goal with very different means?

Comment: @Lohoris Almost every RPG satisfies this scenario. The question isn't looking for an RPG that works only in this way, but for an RPG that works when played this way. That's pretty much every RPG. Even if they want explicit rules for this scenario, that's still hundreds. If they want explicit rules for 1:1 ratios between GM and players but combinable into a 1:many ratio at the end, that's still many games.

Comment: @Zachiel I'll be glad to meet you in the chat today to talk about that ! I know of a lot of RPGs apart from D&D Vampire... but none of the one you mentioned.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am not looking for a RPG that allow 1:1, but for a RPG that allows 1:1x3 or 1:1x4. That is quite different. And I am not looking for a Ruleset or a universe to do what I want, but a methodology (even better if it comes from someone who tried this before) or if not existing, a way to get through the problems I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Rolling back to revision 1, as apparently revision 2 does not line up with what Saffron is asking for.

Comment: @Saffron Would the DM advice for a module like Vault of the Dracolitch (modified for each group to be a party of one) answer your question? http://diehardgamefan.com/2013/10/29/tabletop-review-dd-next-vault-of-the-dracolich-dungeons-dragons/  (trying to understand scope)